# Get an object using scope instead of array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller i have the following

```
  def index
   if !params[:place_id].nil? || !params[:place_id].empty? 
    @restaurant = GoogleSearchedLocation.registered(params[:place_id])
   else
      redirect_to customers_url
    end
  end
```

While in my model I have the following scope defined

```
scope :registered , -> (place_id) { where(:place_id => place_id) }
```

Output is expected as below i.e in the form of array

> < GoogleSearchedLocation id: 1, place_id: "ChIJSeoh6hkEGTkRsd0e1crAbHU", name: "Dunkin' Donuts", rating: 4.3,
>   longitude: nil, latitude: nil, scope: "GOOGLE", created_at:
>   "2015-10-15 10:59:23", updated_at: "2015-10-15 10:59:23">

I tried to convert it into object in my controller function like below

```
 @restaurant1= @restaurant[0].each_slice().map{|a| GoogleSearchedLocation.new(a)}
```

But it's throwing error

> undefined method `each_slice' for
>   < GoogleSearchedLocation:0x00000005345cb0>

Can anyone explain the reason for error while we all know the each_slice() function . And kindly suggest a reasonable way to convert this kind of array into object

Comment: `@restaurant.first` should give you the first object of `ActiveRecord relation`

Comment: Oops i didn't know the answer could be such a simple

Comment: :), just for clarity, I would use `restaurants = GoogleSearchedLocation.registered(params[:place_id])` and `@restaurant = restaurants.first`, or something like that, coz your scope always returns a collection of objects and its better if your variable name to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `GoogleSearchedLocation.registered(params[:place_id]).first` to take the first found record.

---

Also note that for such simple queries there are ActiveRecord helpers like `find_by_something`. Check out this:

```
@restaurant = GoogleSearchedLocation.find_by_place_id(params[:place_id])
```

**P.S.**

You could use `params[:place_id].blank?` in your condition:

```
nil.blank?
# => true

''.blank?
# => true 

'12'.blank?
# => false
```

Comment: actually it doesnt need to check at all, coz it always return an `ActiveRecord relation` even the `id` send as `nil`